# i want to make this query faster

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
    `per_in`, `per_out`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `time`, `per_in`, `per_out`
    FROM
        `10.255.246.186_10113`
    WHERE
        `time` BETWEEN '1551378600' AND '1551724200') AS T1
WHERE
    `per_in` BETWEEN '10.0' AND '20.0'
        OR `per_out` BETWEEN '10.0' AND '20.0'
```

and each table contains data 10 millions or more but not less.

Comment: thankyou suresh sir

Comment: do you have any solutions for me

Comment: Why do you use nested select statement?

Comment: You don't need nested select here. Don't select `time` field if you don't need it in the final select. Are there any indexes on `time`, `per_in`, `per_out`. Possible composite indexes on `time,per_in` and `time,per_out`.

Comment: because i can't get correct output from mysql without using nested querys

Comment: Type it quicker.

Comment: can you run explain before the select you will able to see what the query using and how. 
if you using mysql workbench you will have like an icon of query explian will show you how you pull data.
i think inorder to make the query much faster use indexes. it may make it run much more faster.
take a look here :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html
index tell the mysql how to cut the data and where to look for. there is some index types (b-tree, hashes).

look at @gvgvgvijayan answer down. for the query answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
    `time`, `per_in`, `per_out`
FROM
    `10.255.246.186_10113`
WHERE
    (`time` BETWEEN '1551378600' AND '1551724200')
        AND ((`per_in` BETWEEN '10.0' AND '20.0')
        OR `per_out` BETWEEN '10.0' AND '20.0')
```

Comment: sorry it gives me wrong output

Comment: I have update solution. Please get new solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT time
 , per_in
 , per_out
  FROM `10.255.246.186_10113`
 WHERE time BETWEEN 1551378600 AND 1551724200      
   AND per_in < 20.0
   AND per_out > 10.0
```

This is a terrible name for a table, and highly symptomatic of suboptimal design.

For further help, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). In addition, questions about query performance require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score -1):

try to make views and then apply procedure

Answer (score -1):

This SELECT is equivalent to following:

```
SELECT `per_in`,`per_out` FROM 
   `10.255.246.186_10113` 
   WHERE (`time` BETWEEN '1551378600' AND '1551724200') 
         AND 
        (
          (`per_in` BETWEEN '10.0' AND '20.0')
          OR 
          (`per_out` BETWEEN '10.0' AND '20.0')
        )
```